# "When the revolution comes, you will do as you are told"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, speech

Rememeber reading this in Reader's digest or some novel. "When the revolution comes, you will do as you are told" Cannot find any references in Google. Maybe wrong spelling? The meaning seemed to be that one revolution will lead to just a different set of rules and rulers. Not much will change for the common man. Is this understanding correct? Does anyone know which book/ incident/ speech this is from?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22when+the+revolution+comes%22+%22you+will+do%22&sxsrf=ALeKk010NeymIm4nrzp7JyqAbZx9_go2pw:1591375906695&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLmf2ckevpAhVoIjQIHYk8DsgQ_AUoAXoECAsQCQ&biw=1098&bih=461

Comment: 'When the revolution comes, comrade,' proclaims the orator, 'You will do as you're bloody well told.'

Comment: As opposed to "Not much will change for the common man," the new situation will force you to following orders, desirable or not.

Comment: In 1984 Margaret Thatcher told Mikhail Gorbachev in a speech that the Communist slogan was "Brothers - when you are free, you will do as you are told", but I doubt very much that she originated the saying. It is quite often parroted by conservatives.